# VB.NET httpwebrequest POST text file

Tags: vb.net, post, httpwebrequest, webrequest, postman

I have a VB.NET console program that posts a text file through webrequest. My problem is when the file is a little bit large, the program posts the file but I don't get any response because the console remains active and running for hours (I need to get the response to fill my log file). 
When I have a small file, it works perfectly and I get the response.

I have tried to post the large file manually via POSTMAN on google chrome, and it worked just fine (took 16 mins to post), but the response was "OK 200" which means the file was posted successfully. So if it was a connection issue, it should have taken hours on Postman as well because I tried it with the same connection. There is something like timeout going on when it is ran using VB.NET (although I have set the request.Timeout to -1 in my code)

I need to know what should be changed in my code in order to oblige the program to get the response in case of large files.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Linq
'Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dateTime As String = " "
        Dim createddate As String = " "
        Dim headerbytelength() As Byte
        Dim endboundlength() As Byte
        dateTime = DateAndTime.Now.ToString()
        createddate = DateAndTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssfff")
        Dim e As String = "FNB1150514.TXT"
        Dim strRequestURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("strRequestURL").ToString()
        Dim strFilename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Path") + e
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(strRequestURL), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Method = "POST"
        CType(request, HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = ".NET Framework Example Client"
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Dim JSONResponse As String = ""
        Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogPath"), True)
        writer.WriteLine("")
        writer.WriteLine("File name: " + e + "    Date/Time: " + createddate)
        writer.WriteLine("")

        Try
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Delay"))
            Dim boundary As String = IO.Path.GetRandomFileName
            Dim header As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            header.AppendLine("--" & boundary)
            header.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file"";")
            header.AppendFormat("filename=""{0}""", IO.Path.GetFileName(strFilename))
            header.AppendLine()
            header.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/octet-stream")
            header.AppendLine()
            Dim headerbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header.ToString)
            Dim endboundarybytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vbNewLine & "--" & boundary & "--" & vbNewLine)
            headerbytelength = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header.ToString)
            endboundlength = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vbNewLine & "--" & boundary & "--" & vbNewLine)
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
            request.Timeout = -1
            request.KeepAlive = True
            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = False
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
            'request.ContentLength = 0
            request.ContentLength = headerbytes.Length + New IO.FileInfo(strFilename).Length + endboundarybytes.Length

            Dim s As IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream
            s.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length)
            Dim filebytes() As Byte = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(strFilename)
            s.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length)
            s.Write(endboundarybytes, 0, endboundarybytes.Length)
            s.Close()

            response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Dim receiveStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
            Dim readStream As New StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8)

            Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(readStream.ReadToEnd)
            Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jResults.Children().ToList()
            For Each item As JProperty In results
                item.CreateReader()
                If item.Name = "message" Then
                    writer.WriteLine(item.Value.ToString)
                End If
                If item.Name = "status" Then
                    writer.WriteLine(item.Value.ToString)
                End If
                If item.Name = "errors" Then
                    Dim i As Integer = 0
                    Dim spl() As String = Split(item.Value.ToString, "],")
                    Do Until i > spl.Length - 1
                        writer.WriteLine(spl(i))
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
            Next

            If File.Exists(strFilename) Then
                File.Move(strFilename, (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HistPath") + createddate + "__" + e).ToString())
                writer.WriteLine("BLU File " + e + " was moved to: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HistPath"))
            End If

            response.Close()
            readStream.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.Message = "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." Then
                writer.WriteLine("BLU File " + e + " is empty")
                If File.Exists(strFilename) Then
                    File.Move(strFilename, (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HistPath") + e).ToString())
                    writer.WriteLine("BLU File " + e + " was moved to: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HistPath"))
                End If
            Else
                writer.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
            End If
        End Try
        writer.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------END------------------------------------------------")
        writer.Close()
    End Sub

End Module
```